# How to retrieve the content/file in JSP?

Tags: java, json, jsp

I have a question about the JSP. I have a JSON file in the server and the content is like the following:

```
{ "class":
    {
        "number": 2,
        "student": 
        {
        "name": "Tom",
        "age": 1
        },
        "student": 
        {
        "name": "May",
        "age": 2
        }
    }
}
```

when I type the URL (e.g. `1.1.1.1`), it will display the content like the above.

And, in my JSP page, I have call this url in order to display the JSON content. However, I don't know use WHAT object/or class to call and retrieve the file.

Does the JSP/Java provide some classes do that? Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused....do you want to download JSON file or some other file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [URLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) to retrieve the content

[Here](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) is a sample for the same